# How to prove that $(A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \lor B) = B$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

I know this is fairly basic, and I understand that it becomes 
$$
\begin{align}
(A \land \lnot A) \lor B \\
F \lor B \\
B 
\end{align}
$$

However, I can't work out how to prove that it becomes that first line. It seems intuitive, but I cannot work out which laws let me simplify it like that.

This is from a previous homework, and the above equation is the correction I was given, and I can't remember exactly how it was produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line follows from distributivity:
$$(X \wedge Y) \vee Z = (X \vee Z) \wedge (Y \vee Z)$$
Think what $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are in this scenario.

Comment: Would $X=(A \lor B), Y=\lnot A, |=B$?
Giving $((A \lor B) \lor B) \land (\lnot A \lor B) =
$(A \land (\lnot A \lor B) =
$(A \land \lnot A) \lor (A \land B)$ by distributivity of $\land $

Comment: No. $X=A$, $Y= \neg A$ and $Z=B$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 5):

As Clive pointed out, this comes from an application of the distributive law of  "disjunction" $(\lor)$ over "conjunction" $(\land)$:

$$(\color{red}{\bf P}\color{blue}{\bf \lor R}) \color{red}{\bf \land} (\color{red}{\bf Q} \color{blue}{\bf \lor R})\iff (\color{red}{\bf P \land Q}) \color{blue}{\bf \lor R}$$

In your problem, you have:
$$(\color{red}{\bf A} \color{blue}{\bf \lor B}) \color{red}{\bf \land} (\color{red}{\bf \lnot A} \color{blue}{\bf \lor B}) \iff (\color{red}{\bf A \land \lnot A}) \color{blue}{\bf \lor B}$$

---

You'll also want to become familiar with the other application of distributivity (which is not needed in your problem). It follows a similar pattern, with connectives interchanged, as follows:

$$(P\land R){\bf \lor }(Q\land R) \iff (P \lor Q) \land R$$

Comment: That's great, thanks! I was definitely confused about distributivity, this is really useful.

Comment: Nice amy :-) nice to see u

Comment: Just note that each side of the distributive equivalence implies the other. So you can start from the left hand side to obtain the right hand side, and vice versa.

Comment: @amWhy: Not only color coded, but using my fav red-white-blue! +1